# JCE Java 8 Update 152 - How to set unlimited?

Tags: java

I see that the jre libs now include the limited and unlimited files. That is all fine and good.

But how do I enable unlimited?

Answer (score 1):

It is explained in the release note:

- [JDK 8u152 Update Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u152-relnotes-3850503.html)

It says:

> "To enable unlimited cryptography, one can use the new `crypto.policy` Security property. If the new Security property (`crypto.policy`) is set in the `java.security` file, or has been set dynamically using the `Security.setProperty()` call before the JCE framework has been initialized, that setting will be honored. By default, the property will be undefined. If the property is undefined and the legacy JCE jurisdiction files don't exist in the legacy lib/security directory, then the default cryptographic level will remain at 'limited'. To configure the JDK to use unlimited cryptography, set the `crypto.policy` to a value of 'unlimited'."